# How do I change pwdMaxAge on a "specialized password policy?"

Tags: ldap

I'm supporting dsee7 (Oracle/Sun LDAP server) and I have a "specialized password policy" for non human accounts called, SrvsPasswdPolicy.

"pwdPolicySubentry: cn=SrvsPasswdPolicy,cn=config"

I need to modify pwdMaxAge so that passwords never expire. Why passwords were set on these accounts in the first place I'll probably never know . . .

At this point I can't even figure out how to print the policy to screen.

Should I be using dsconf or ldapsearch?

OK, remembered how to print the policy:

> cn=SrvcsPasswdPolicy,cn=config objectClass- top objectClass-
>   ldapsubentry objectClass- pwdPolicy objectClass- sunPwdPolicy cn-
>   ServcsPasswdPolicy description- A password policy intended for
>   proxy or service accounts. pwdAllowUserChange- FALSE pwdAttribute-
>   userPassword pwdCheckQuality- 0 pwdExpireWarning- 0 pwdInHistory- 0
>   pwdLockout- FALSE pwdMaxAge- 0 pwdMinAge- 0 pwdMaxFailure- 32700
>   pwdMustChange- FALSE passwordStorageScheme- SSHA
>   passwordRootdnMayBypassModsChecks- off pwdMinLength- 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update, I can see you already have set a pwdMaxAge of 0, so this is unnecesary.

```
ldapmodify -h server -D BINDUSER -w bindpwd
dn: cn=SrvsPasswdPolicy,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: pwdMaxAge
pwdMaxAge: 0
```

Remember to delete the passwordexpirationtime attribute of those users!

Use this search filter to check which users have expiration times:

```
(&(passwordexpirationtime=*)(pwdPolicySubentry=cn=SrvsPasswdPolicy,cn=config))
```

Comment: using ldapmodify? Using an ldif file?

Comment: `ldapmodify -v -a -f ServicePasswdPolicy.ldif  -D 'cn=Directory Manager'
replace pwdMaxAge:
        0
!modifying entry "cn=SrvcsPasswdPolicy,cn=config"
`
   

Thanks for the answer!